# Calling SSIS package from .Net

Tags: .net, ssis

I am calling SSIS package from a .Net windows UI. Both SSIS & .Net app are created in 2008. The SSIS package is stored in file system. When I ran .Net app I got error:

> The package failed to load due to
>   error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from
>   XML. No further detailed error
>   information can be specified for this
>   problem because no Events object was
>   passed where detailed error
>   information can be stored.". This
>   occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML
>   fails.

Exception Detail -

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException was unhandled
  HelpLink="#-1073659847"
  Message="The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 \"Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.\". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.\r\n"
  Source=""
  ErrorCode=-1073672184
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents events, Boolean loadNeutral)
       at SSISCall.Form1.Execute_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\SSISCall\SSISCall\Form1.cs:line 36
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at SSISCall.Program.Main() in D:\SSISCall\SSISCall\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
       HelpLink="#-1073659847"
       Message="The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 \"Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.\". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.\r\n"
       Source=""
       ErrorCode=-1073672184
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.LoadPackage(String FileName, Boolean loadNeutral, IDTSEvents90 pEvents)
            at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents events, Boolean loadNeutral)
       InnerException:
```

The code that I am using is very simple:

```
string packageLocation;
Package ssisPackage;
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.
Application ssisApplication;
DTSExecResult ssisPackageResult;
packageLocation =@"D:\SSISCall\Package.dtsx";
ssisApplication =new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
ssisPackage = ssisApplication.LoadPackage(packageLocation,null); ----Getting error here
ssisPackageResult = ssisPackage.Execute();
Console.WriteLine(ssisPackageResult.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

**Please suggest.**

Comment: Does the problem occur when you execute the package from the command line, in other words, outside your .NET app?  Also, does the package attempt to load any files or any other packages?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have SSIS components installed on the computer where you are executing this package?  If not, it won't run - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403348.aspx

Is the version of SSIS installed on the computer 2008?  If not, it won't run - 2005 and 2008 parts are not interchangeable.

Is drive "D" a mapped drive?  If so, your code probably won't run unattended (with a not-logged-in user session) - use UNC paths instead.

Answer (score 1):

Getting exactly same error on the Lame loadPackage  call.

This code was working fine for SQL 2005.

EnvDTE90 doesn't look like add any functionality to the DTS Application model.

Referencing both EnvDTE80 and EnvDTE90 doesn't make any differnece